# Hibernate Search not indexing email address?

Tags: groovy, spring-boot, hibernate-search

I want to full text search for email addresses in an entity using Hibernate Search.

Given the following entity "Person" with the indexed field "email":

## Person.groovy

```
package com.example

import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
import javax.persistence.GenerationType
import javax.persistence.Id

import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Field
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Indexed

@Entity
@Indexed
class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id

    @Field
    String email
}
```

and given the Repository

## SearchRepository.groovy

```
package com.example

import javax.persistence.EntityManager

import org.apache.lucene.search.Query
import org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextEntityManager
import org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search
import org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.QueryBuilder
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository

@Repository
class SearchRepository {

    @Autowired
    EntityManager entityManager

    FullTextEntityManager getFullTextEntityManager() {
        Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager)
    }

    List<Person> findPeople(String searchText){
        searchText = searchText.toLowerCase()+'*'
        QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.searchFactory
                .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Person).get()
        Query query =
                qb
                .keyword()
                .wildcard()
                .onField('email')
                .matching(searchText)
                .createQuery()

        javax.persistence.Query jpaQuery =
                fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query, Person)

        jpaQuery.resultList
    }
}
```

then the following Test fails:

## SearchWildcardTest.groovy

```
package com.example

import javax.persistence.EntityManager

import org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextEntityManager
import org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = HibernateSearchWildcardApplication)
@Transactional
class SearchWildcardTest {

    @Autowired
    SearchRepository searchRepo

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepo

    @Autowired
    EntityManager em

    FullTextEntityManager getFullTextEntityManager() {
        Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em)
    }

    @Test
    void findTeamsByNameWithWildcard() {
        Person person = personRepo.save new Person(email: 'foo@bar.com')

        fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait()
        fullTextEntityManager.flushToIndexes()

        List<Person> people = searchRepo.findPeople('foo@bar.com')

        assert people.contains(person)  // this assertion fails! Why?
    }
}
```

## PersonRepository.groovy

```
package com.example

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository

interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long>{
}
```

## build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.2.7.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath('io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.2.RELEASE')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

jar {
    baseName = 'hibernate-search-email'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy')
    compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-search:5.3.0.Final')
    testCompile('com.h2database:h2')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.8'
}
```

Here is what Luke shows from the generated Lucene Index after running the test:

[image]

It seems to me that the email address "foo@bar.com" is not completely stored in the index, but instead is torn apart into the two string "foo" and "bar.com".

The "Getting started" guide from the official [Hibernate Search website](http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/getting-started/) 
states that

> [...] The standard tokenizer splits words at punctuation characters and hyphens while keeping email addresses and internet hostnames intact. It is a good general purpose tokenizer. [...]

I must be something missing here but wasn't able to figure it out.

My questions:

- Why does my code not index the complete email address?
- How do I achieve it to index the address so that the test passes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the docs reflect a change in the underlying Lucene APIs not correctly.

> [K]eeping email addresses and internet hostnames intact...

This used to be correct for the traditional `StandardTokenizer` which since then has been altered on the Lucene side. Its behavior can be found in `ClassicTokenizer` nowadays.

So the following configuration should give you what you are after:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@AnalyzerDef(
    name = "emailanalyzer",
    tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = ClassicTokenizerFactory.class),
    filters = {
        @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
    }
)
class Person {

    // ...

    @Field
    @Analyzer(definition = "emailanalyzer")
    String email;
}
```

Note that trimming is also applied with this configuration. We'll adapt the HSEARCH documentation accordingly, thanks for spotting this!